# First order logic formulae

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Prove that $$((\forall x) ( a \Rightarrow b)) \Rightarrow [((\forall x)( a)) \Rightarrow ((\forall x) (b)) ]$$ is valid first order formula. Where ' a ' and 'b' are first order formulae.

My attempt:
$(\forall x) (\neg a \lor b) \Rightarrow \exists x (\neg a \lor b)  \Rightarrow \exists x (\neg a) \lor \exists x(b) \Rightarrow \neg(\forall x)(a) \lor \exists x(b) \Rightarrow \forall x (a) \Rightarrow \exists 
x (b)$

I am not able to get the RHS . What is wrong with this method?

Comment: Use mathjax to format your post

Comment: It depends on the axioms and rules; it can be an [axiom](http://us.metamath.org/mpeuni/ax-4.html).

Comment: The way you are following will be difficult, because (in general) $\forall$ does not dostribute over $\lor$.

Comment: With Natural Deduction is starightforward.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: even if it is an axiom it still needs to be proved valid, doesn't it?

Comment: Prove it by contradiction. Assume the antecedent and assume that every $x$ is $as$. Then assume (for contradiction) that there is an $x_0$ that is not $b$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA i know $\forall doesn't distribute over \or , i have converted \for all into \exists then applied distribution

Comment: To directly answer your question "what's wrong with this method": At the first $\implies$, by going from $\forall$ to $\exists$, you've given up too much information. Unfortunately, $\exists x\,(\neg a\lor b)$ does not imply the RHS that you want; there are counterexample models with just two elements.

Comment: $\exists x (\lnot a \lor b)$ is not a strong enough claim to prove the conclusion.